# Modify time until DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE is sent

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, usb

Is there a way to trigger the USB Device Discovery of Windows, such that removed devices are detected faster?

I have a USB Serial modem that I unplug (the USB plug, not the serial one). I want to detect the `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` event which is sent as soon as the unplugging is detected (That's what I assume). The detection of the Event works as desired, it is sent sometimes 1s after removal, sometimes several minutes after removal.

Is there a way to decrease the refresh interval, or another way to make this event getting sent faster?

Comment: Is the `WM_COMMAND` being called when the USB device is removed? What does a call to `GetRawInputDeviceList()` return during this time (when the message has not been processed/received)?

Comment: No `WM_COMMAND` appears in my code. Do i have to notify something about the fact that i unplugged the device? That seems weird.

Comment: I executed `GetRawInputDeviceList()` before and after removing the device. There were no differences.

Comment: I assume you have a function that handles messages? It will probably switch based on the message that you receive as a call back. Inside this switch statement is probably a check for `WM_COMMAND` in which you check for `DBT__DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`? Could you post the function containing this handling?

Comment: That is in code i have not written and i may not change or publish it. There is a switch for a UINT to be WM_DEVICECHANGE and inside a check whether a WPARAM is DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE. A breakpoint in there is hit some time after unplugging the device. But this interval can be several minutes. That is what i want to change. So the Code as it is working, i just want to be able to poll for device changes or decrease the refresh interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE is sent after Windows decides it has detected the removal, and you can't influence that, at least not in the general case. There are various things that make Windows do this faster or slower (type of device, current "data flow" with the device, the device itself), and it also varies between OS versions. What I found helps to some degree in some of cases is to remove, from the Registry, references to USB devices that were plugged into that USB port before (there are various utilities for this).

At the extreme, since this is a Windows Broadcast message (non-queued), there will not be another one sent in until the previous is processed. Thus, you may not receive it at all! To solve that, keep message handling fast and simple and *don't* set a breakpoint there while debugging.

Also, having a separate Windows and Thread for the specific purpose of handling USB device arrival/removal notifications may help.

But, from my experience, polling will not help, as the main problems seems to be in the criteria Windows uses to detect the removal. The time from that event until you receive the message is small. Of course, in your case this may not be true - to find out, use a tool like SysInternals Process Monitor. Depending on what you see going on there, there may be something you can do to make it faster.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with the registry, can you give me some hints where to remove the those references? I have found the ports used by the device in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_0403&PID_E510`. Do i have to remove something in there or just the whole device type? What will that affect?

Comment: It's been a while since I did that, I'm not sure what tools I used back then. Examples are: Symantec USB Oblivion, GhostBuster (on CodePlex)... I tweaked the Registry a few times "by hand", but when I found the tools, I gave up, as it's always a PITA. :) As for the consequences, this will simply make Windows "forget" that there is such a device and make the Registry smaller, thus faster to search.